# Link a new model in C# like Ruby

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, entity-framework

I recently went from `Ruby on Rails` to `C#` using `.NET`.

In Ruby you can link a new model using `new CurrentUser.newmodel`as long as the `newmodel` has a `UserId` and that model will be linked to that user. Also you can pull up that model using `CurrentUser.newmodel` and query any attributes from that model that you want. For this you need a one to one relationship with ActiveRecord. For Example in Ruby you would use

```
class newmodel

  belongs_to :currentuser

  //other code here that doesn't matter within this question
end
```

Is there a way I can make my models do something like this with Entity?

Comment: LINQ is a query language to anything, not an ORM. You should be comparing Rails to NHibernate, Entity Framework or other ORMs.

Comment: Ah I apologize, I meant Entity. I will edit that. Thank you

Comment: Yeah there are many ways to do this but it is more complicated in entity-framework than ruby. Without knowing how you have coded your database I can't really help you though there are plenty of tutorials out there though just find one that works with the way you have made you database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have defined your models in Entity Framework, you can map objects in relationships as in Rails. The syntax is almost the same even, for the actual assignment part:

```
Person bob = new Person();
Job j = new Job();
bob.Job = j;
```

When saved, the ID of j will be saved into the Person table to persist the relationship.

Comment: This isn't the same. In Ruby you don't need to create the classes, they are created dynamically by the language. In EF you need to create classes with all the attributes you want to access. AFAIK only F#'s type providers provide such functionality

Comment: Yes, this is true.  I was not talking about how the classes are created, though, just how the assignment happens (as I said).  His question seemed to me to be about how the persistence happens, so that is what I was trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment but Panagiotis seems to be right - you are asking wrong question probably. 
A first I tought that you are looking for assigning specific user profile for application. if so - please see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281602/ASP-NET-Profile-Provider and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

But if you are looking for relationship persistence (like one-to-one, one-to-many etc.), you have to be more specific about the data layer you are using.

EDIT:

In opposite to dynamic languages like Ruby and Python, C# is very "strict" in terms of object modeling, so if you want to use the syntax like `User.Whatever`, `Whatever` has to be declared class. The only way to implement flexible object attributes is to use some kind of dictionary or list.

Sample implementation could be:

```
public class User{
    public User(){
      AdditionalAttributes=new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes{get; set;}
}
```

and then

```
var user=new User();
user["belongs_to"]=currentUser
```

but it can be still tricky to store such relation.

Comment: You are correct. I edited it, but essentially yes it would be a one to one where you would have to use belongs_to in Rails normally. I'm just not sure how to convert that to C#